When conducting a blind test how many correct answers on average can be considered random?
If an infinite (or large) number of individuals are given a blind test, how many correct answers should the average individual get by pure luck?
We assume that the blind test is really a blind test. So any correct answer is just a lucky coincidence.
For example, an infinite or large number of individuals drink 6 different types of de-identified Cola soft drinks (numbered 1 to 6). Individuals know which Cola soft drinks are included in the test but not the order in which they are served. Individuals write down their answers. Individuals can then have anywhere between zero and six correct answers.
How do you calculate how many correct answers the average individual can be expected to have?
One way I think of is to calculate the probability of a participant getting all 6 soft drinks right. Then subtract that probability from 1. If the difference is greater than 0.5, you continue by subtracting the probability of 5 correct soft drinks. And so on, until you get below P=0.5.
But this method doesn't tell me exactly how many right the average individual would have.

Exactly five correct answers is impossible.

... unless some individuals choose to assign the same number to multiple drinks.

I would do 1/6 for first choice, then for second choice 1/6 or 1/5 depending on first choice good or not, an so on... The branching might be a little tedious to sum though. Maybe it's more practical the use the number of swaps to get to correct answer as a metric.

This can be done using linearity of expectation. If you guess randomly then the probability that you get any particular drink right is $\frac{1}{6}$. So by linearity of expectation, the expected number of drinks you guess correctly is
$$6 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \boxed{ 1 }.$$
This is despite the fact that the events of getting different drinks right are not independent! (If you get one drink right there are fewer possibilities for the other drinks, so you're more likely to get the other drinks right.) Linearity of expectation is very useful in this way because it doesn't require independence. This argument shows more generally that the expected number of fixed points of a random permutation of $n$ objects is $1$, and in particular, maybe surprisingly, it does not depend on $n$.
However, this doesn't quite answer the question in the title:

how many correct answers on average can be considered random?

This requires saying a bit more about the distribution of correct answers when you're guessing randomly. It is possible to compute the probabilities exactly but the following approximation is simpler and also, unlike the exact answer, does not depend on $n$: the distribution of correct answers is approximately a Poisson distribution $\text{Pois}(1)$, so

the probability of getting no right answers is approximately $e^{-1} \approx 0.368 \dots$,
the probability of getting $1$ right answer is also approximately $e^{-1} \approx 0.368 \dots$,
the probability of getting $2$ right answers is approximately $\frac{e^{-1}}{2!} \approx 0.182 \dots$,

and already these add up to $0.92 \dots $. So if someone gets between $0$ and $2$ right answers that's indistinguishable from chance. But getting $3$ or more is more surprising (although in a large sample some people will still do this). And the probability of getting all $6$ is $\frac{1}{6!} \approx 0.0014 \dots $ so that's quite surprising, although in a large sample you can still expect it to happen by chance (for this we need about $700$ people).
So, if you're given blind test results for a large sample of people, you can compare the distribution of numbers of correct answers you get to the Poisson distribution, and if they look similar then the results are indistinguishable from chance. But if there are significantly more people getting, say, $\ge 4$ drinks right than the Poisson distribution predicts then maybe there's some signal.

Note to readers: It even works irrespective of whether you make choose a random permutation of the drinks, or just make one of six choices randomly six times.
